# Disable Laravel Redis Cache

Tags: laravel, redis

i have set up the laravel Eloquent ORM query with Redis cache, i.e 
->remember(10)->get(), for 10 mintues cache, 
however, i want to disable all the cache somehow when I am working on the development site, on production site, the cache need to be turned on.

how can I turn on and off the cache without removing the ->remember(10) from the query? Because i have many query and do not want to remove them one by one in development site and add them all in production site.

i have tried ->remember(0), -1, none, all not working, the redis cache still working.. any one can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have an environment file (`.env`) where you can set up the cache driver. Use the array or file driver on the development environment and redis on your production environment.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: Use `array` as cache driver if you want to turn off the cache completely.